# Cannot read in files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a small problem with reading in my file. My code:

```
import csv as csv
import numpy 

with open("train_data.csv","rb") as training:
    csv_file_object = csv.reader(training)
    header = csv_file_object.next()

    data = []
    for row in csv_file_object:
        data.append(row)
    data = numpy.array(data)
```

I get the error no such file "train_data.csv", so I know the problem lies with the location. But whenever I specify the pad like this: open("C:\Desktop...etc) it doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So where is the file in relation to your code, and how are you running it?

Comment: It is looking for `train_data.csv` in the same directory as the python file is in.

Comment: @karthikr actually in the directory he's running his command from - not always the same thing

Comment: You'll want to escape the backslashes or do this when you put the whole path in. `r"C:\Desktop\train_data.csv"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give the full file path, your script should work.  Since it is not, it must be that you have escape characters in your path.  To fix this, use a raw-string to specify the file path:

```
# Put an 'r' at the start of the string to make it a raw-string.
with open(r"C:\path\to\file\train_data.csv","rb") as training:
```

Raw strings do not process escape characters.

Also, just a technical fact, not giving the full file path causes Python to look for the file in the directory that the script is launched from.  If it is not there, an error is thrown.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke - True, but they are risky.  It is best to protect against them.  Also, say in the future Python introduces a new escape character.  Then, any file path that contains that character will now not work.

Comment: You can also avoid it (even on Windows) by using the forward slash "`/`". On modern versions of windows, `C:/path/to/file/train_data.csv` is a valid filepath.

Comment: Things like `\\` should also work.
@iCodez that is true, but making sure old code works on new Python is a bit of a tricky game :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `open()` and Windows you need to deal with the backslashes properly.

Option 1.) Use the [raw string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), this will be the string prefixed with an `r`.

```
open(r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\train_data.csv')
```

Option 2.) Escape the backslashes

```
open('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\train_data.csv')
```

Option 3.) Use forward slashes

```
open('C:/Users/Me/Desktop/train_data.csv')
```

As for finding the file you are using, if you just do `open('train_data.csv')` it is looking in the directory you are running the python script from. So, if you are running it from `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\`, your `train_data.csv` needs to be on the desktop as well.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation!